# Editing datagridview that is populated by a complex query

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I am populating a datagridview from a query. Once presented, the grid should allow editing of individual cells but it does not.

I am populating a datagridview from a query. Once presented, the grid should allow editing of individual cells but it does not even though I have set individual columns to readonly = false.

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        myEntityData_testEntities ctx;
        BindingSource bindingSource1;
            public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ctx = new testEntities();
            bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

            bindingSource1.DataSource = (from s in ctx.Surveys
                               from u in ctx.Users


     from st in ctx.SurveyTemplates
                       where (s.UserID.Equals(u.ID) && s.SurveyTemplateID.Equals(st.ID))
                       select new
                       {
                           s.ID,
                           s.InvitationText,
                           s.Status,
                           s.UserID,
                           u.FirstName,
                           u.LastName,
                           st.Name
                       }).ToList();
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        dc.ReadOnly = false;
    }

    dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)`enter code here`
{
    dataGridView1.Update();


  }
```

Comment: `DataGridView` is view control, it's responsibility is to display data and provide UI components for editing. You need to write the code which will update database when value in `DataGridView` is changed.

Comment: `dataGridView1.Update();` will just redraw component on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The `BindingSource.DataSource` property is set to a `List<AnonymousType>`.

In C#, the properties of anonymous types are read-only (immutable).  Hence the DGV cells are also read-only.

From: [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)

> Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of
>   read-only properties into a single object without having to explicitly
>   define a type first.

Just define a class with the required properties and `select` a new instance of that class  with the properties set.

Edit: Example (based on original query)

```
        bindingSource1.DataSource = (from s in ctx.Surveys
                                     from u in ctx.Users
                                     from st in ctx.SurveyTemplates
                                     where (s.UserID.Equals(u.ID) && s.SurveyTemplateID.Equals(st.ID))
                                     select new NotAnonymousType 
                                     {
                                         ID = s.ID,
                                         InvitationText = s.InvitationText,
                                         Status = s.Status,
                                         UserID = s.UserID,
                                         FirstName = u.FirstName,
                                         LastName = u.LastName,
                                         Name = st.Name
                                     }).ToList();
```

...

```
    internal class NotAnonymousType
    {
        public Int32 ID { get; set; }
        public string InvitationText { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of this?

Comment: Cannot initialize type 'Form1.NotAnonymousType with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'